# How to make sure processing is handled gracefully

Tags: c#, process, task, exit

I would like my application to end gracefully. Is it possible to do so? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Here is a general overview of what the application looks like:

```
// .NET Core Console App
while (true)
{
    // Get the next message from the Queue. The Queue is a database table that contains a list of "things that need to be done".

    // Spawn a Task to handle that message. Send the Task all the data it requires to complete. Generally speaking, the Task will collate all the data in an object and make a call (PUT, POST, DELETE) against a set of RESTful web services.

    // Sleep for some time.
    Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeInSeconds * 1000);
}
```

This app will normally run non-stop on some server. But if a user needs to bring it down, I would like the job to exit gracefully:

- Stop querying the queue for any more messages. Queried messages are locked by the database, so that other processes can't process the same message.
- Allow any running tasks to complete.

Is it possible to accomplish this? What technologies/libraries/concepts could I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the complexity of managing jobs in your code, you could use a third party package, namely [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Essentially, you will fire and forget your jobs, and let another process handle running those. If your app goes down, the hangfire server would keep running.